# AWS API Gateway WebSocket not receiving data in real-time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I'm building a minimal chat application and I'm using Amazon API Gateway WebSocket with Lambda Integration.

But when I try to send a message, a wierd thing happens: I receive message only when I send one..and I'll get the last-1 message.

But the strangest thing is that this behavior happens only in prod environment. In the dev environment (with the very same code) it works properly. The infastructure is also deployed with SAM template except for the API Gateway which is manually created (but checked and both dev and prod are the same).

I also tried to delete the API gateway and create it again.
I also tried if some of the code depends on DEV/PROD environment but still nothing.

EDIT:

I've added a ping/pong message just to see when how it behaves, and here is the result:

```
> {"action": "ping"}
> {"action": "ping"}
> {"action": "ping"}
> {"action": "ping"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
> {"action": "ping"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
> {"action": "ping"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
> {"action": "ping"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
> {"action": "ping"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
> {"action": "ping"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
> {"action": "ping"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
> {"action": "ping"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
> {"action": "ping"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
> {"action": "ping"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
> {"action": "ping"}
> {"action": "ping"}
> {"action": "ping"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
< {"type":"ping","message":"Pong!"}
> {"action": "ping"}
```

Comment: You're sending the data in the same way? Same infrastructure 100%? Same account? Same way of testing?

Comment: Hi, yeah it’s 100% the same.. that’s the weird thing. In the faulty env, data are received anyway but only when sending another one

Answer (score 1):

Below the solution for those who might get into the same problem.

Using async within .map() or forEach() methods appears to cause the problem. I don't know why.

Here's an example:

```
// DON'T
arrayOfConnections.forEach(async connectionID => {
  const sent = await WS.sendToOne(connectionId, msgWrapper)
}

// DO
for(let connectionID of arrayOfConnections) {
 const sent = await WS.sendToOne(connectionId, msgWrapper)
}
```